# Would an SQL engine use any approach other than brute-force in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The query below retrieves the median `LAT_N` value from the `STATION` table, by finding the record where the number of `LAT_N` values greater than itself is equal to those less than itself.

```
SELECT ROUND(S.LAT_N, 4) AS MEDIAN FROM STATION S WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < S.LAT_N) = 
(SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > S.LAT_N)
```

It's a smart solution that someone else posted as a solution to a Hackerrank question, but I'm wondering exactly how an SQL engine would approach this.

Would such an unusual query structure only call for brute-forcing the two subqueries until their `COUNT`s are equal, or is there an easy opporunity for optimisation that I'm missing?

(I understand this query does not provide a median in every case. I'm only after an explanation of whether or not an SQL engine would attempt to optimise it to any level better than a brute-force enumeration for each subquery).

Comment: There are other ways to calculate the median, but this is a viable way if you make certain assumptions (such as no ties and an odd number of rows).

Comment: It would be an exceptionally *narrow* use case for the optimizer to be built to have a smart strategy for approaching this query. I doubt that any optimizer can develop an optimal strategy for completing this query building on standard operators and first principles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "smart" solution.  It is clever, but it does not fully solve the problem.  It does not work for an even number of rows, for instance.

Probably the safest method is variables:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(S.LAT_N), 4) AS MEDIAN
FROM (SELECT S.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT S.* FROM STATION S ORDER BY S.LAT_N) S CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     ) S
WHERE 2 * seqnum IN (@rn, @rn + 1, @rn + 2) ;
```

This should work regardless of the number of rows or the distribution of the values.  There is another clever method that uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but its utility is limited to the maximum length of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` intermediate result.

Comment: Yep I understand it doesn't work for an even number of rows, I was simply after an explanation of whether or not an SQL engine would attempt to optimise this query.

Comment: @EdwardGargan . . . And I'm of the opinion that working queries are more important than fast ones.